# Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric using C# and SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am developing a web application and I am calling stored procedure that has insert statement using below code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
conn.Open();

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.Connection = conn;
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "StoredProc1";

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@ReturnValue", SqlDbType.Int);
parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

command.Parameters.Add(parm);

command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@A", SqlDbType.BigInt)).Value = gui.A;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@B", SqlDbType.Int)).Value = gui.B;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@C", SqlDbType.Decimal)).Value = gui.C;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@D", SqlDbType.Float)).Value = gui.D;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@E", SqlDbType.Float)).Value = gui.E;
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@F", SqlDbType.NVarChar)).Value = gui.F;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();

returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(parm.Value);
```

But I am getting an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric

on the `ExecuteNonQuery()` line. May I know what I am missing?

Thanks
Anjanaa

Comment: Show the `gui` class.

Comment: Show also your stored procedure parameter declaration

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem is not entirely in .NET:

1. Check the store procedure to see if the is any calculated value(s) that may exceed the size of a particular type (i.e. A column of data type int may be calculated to equate the size of data type bigint). The potion that is going to contain that information should be of the same data type (i.e. if this information is contained in a temporary table the temporary table should contain a column of that size to contain the data, if a variable is used the variable should be of size that may contain the data, etc)
2. The property / field / variable that is going to contain that data should be of a similar data type (i.e. smallint - sql  = short - .NET, etc).